# C++ Vector datatype compiler error issue with a member of my defined Class

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, stdvector

I'm trying to learn C++ as an interest, and I'm coming up with an issue trying to incorporate a Vector container.

I'm trying to incorporate a vector iterator into my Class, but I'm getting a compile error on this line `std::cout << nodeIterator->data;`, my code snippets below.

Error I'm getting:

> error: request for member 'data' in '* nodeIterator. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator::operator-> [with _Iterator = const FibTree::Node**, _Container = std::vector >]()', which is of non-class type 'const FibTree::Node*'

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node const* left;
        Node const* right;
        Node const* parent;
        int n;
        int level;
        int index;
    
        Node (void);
    
};

// Get root method
Node const* getRoot(void) {
    return this->root;
}

void start(Node const* root) {
    std::vector<Node const*> setsList;
    std::cout << root->data; 
writeSets(setsList, root);
}

writeSets(std::vector<Node const*> &setsList, Node const* cur) {

    std::vector<Node const*>::iterator nodeIterator;

    // Displays all preceding left values
    for (nodeIterator = setsList.begin();nodeIterator != setsList.end(); nodeIterator++)
    {
        std::cout << nodeIterator->data; //*** Get Compile error this line ***
    }

    std::cout << cur->left->data;
    std::cout << cur->right->data;

    setsList.push_back(cur->left);
    writeSets(setsList,cur->right);
    setsList.pop_back();
}
```

Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
Iterator = const FibTree::Node**
```

so when you write `nodeIterator->data` you're requesting `data` from a `const FibTree::Node**` which has no such member hence the error. you need

```
(*nodeIterator)->data
```

**edit** Apart from that your code as shown doesn't compile: `writeSets` has no return type, `getRoot` tries to access `this` which cannot be done in non-member functions and `start` is declared before `writeSets`.

Comment: Thanks very much - you highlighted the issue. Why is there no such `data` member from `const FibTree::Node**`? Could you tell me what the parenthesis are doing here, to be able to access the `data` member. Sorry I've a lot to learn.

Comment: `Node**` is a pointer to a pointer, more specifically it's a pointer that points to a `Node*` - with `->` you access members of what is pointed to. So if you have a variable of type `Node*` that is ok, since `Node` itself has a `data` member. But not for `Node**`. So that is why you use `*nodeIterator`, here the `*` is used to *dereference* the pointer, and the result of dereferencing a `Node**` is `Node*`, which is what you need.

Comment: If the above sounds like Chinese (or any other language you don't speak) to you, start with some basic tutorials, or search around here on StackOverflow. Then, look for some higher level stuff on lists and vectors: the whole premise of what you seem to be trying to achieve with the above code seems wrong (ie. a vector of nodes of a doubly linked list)